# Flow Chart with drag and drop facebook friends

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

I'm an amateur website designer. I want to create a flowchart of a committee and allow the web administrator to drag and drop his facebook friends into the flow chart to fill up roles in the committee. There should be a friend selector beside the flowchart, and when dropped into the flowchart the friends should be added to a Facebook group.

Can anyone point me to the tools needed to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't vote this down. I really need the help, else please point to where I can get the help.

Comment: To be more specific, I'm thinking of a combination of Lucid Chart with Facebook friends as entries

Comment: SO is for issues you encounter during development. Ask on any of the thousands webdeveloper sites out there. Every language has plenty.